# How to replace null value with value from the next row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need support in my sql query code. I have to replace null value in a column with not-null value from the next row.

as a example we can use this code:

```
declare   @value table (r# int, value varchar(15))
insert into @value ( r#, value ) values
 (1, NULL   ) ,
 (2, 'January'), 
 (3, 'February' ), 
 (4, NULL    ),
 (5, 'March'  ),
 (6, NULL    ),
(7, Null  ),
(8, 'December' ),
(9, Null ),
(10, Null  ),
(11, Null  ),
(12, 'November' ),
(13, Null )
select * from @value
```

When I use lead function I get this value but it does not work with NULLs.
What I need is to get:

```
1 January
2 January
3 February
4 March
5 March
6 December
7 December
8 December
9 November
10 November
11 November
12 November
13 NULL
```

Bu from my query :

```
SELECT r#, 
  value
 ,case when value is null  then Lead(value) OVER ( order by  r#  asc) else value end as RESULT 
FROM @value
order by r#
```

I have:[image]

Comment: _Next_ - according to what?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (SQL Server?)

Comment: yes, SQL server. In the column value I have null values and I want to replace them with value from next row(from the same column) for example for row 1 I want January value, for row 9,10 and 11 November

Comment: "I use lead function": please include this code (by editing the question) – otherwise we're guessing how you are approaching the problem.

Comment: Your problem is that `LEAD` is getting the next value. And that might be null as well (in your data it works for January where there is one null, but not for December where you need the next but one row). `LEAD` has no ability to "get next row that meets condition" – for that you need some form of join or inner query (and there are a few options in the answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with window functions.  Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't support the `IGNORE NULL`s option on `LEAD()`, so that is not an option.

However, you can use two levels of window functions:

```
select v.r#, v.value,
       coalesce(v.value, max(value) over (partition by next_r#)) as imputed_value
from (select v.*,
             min(case when value is not null then r# end) over (order by r# desc) as next_r#
      from @value v
     ) v
order by v.r#;
```

On 13 rows, the performance difference is probably not noticeable.  However, this should have much better performance as the number of rows increases.

Comment: @PatrycjaKowalczyk . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 16):

**For all supported versions:**

You may use an additional `APPLY` operator to find the first record with not `NULL` value:

T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
   v1.[r#], 
   COALESCE(v1.[value], v2.[value]) AS [value]
FROM @value v1
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 1 [Value]
   FROM @value 
   WHERE (v1.[r#] < [r#]) AND [value] IS NOT NULL
) v2
```

Output:

```
r#  value
1   January
2   January
3   February
4   March
5   March
6   December
7   December
8   December
9   November
10  November
11  November
12  November
13  NULL
```

**For SQL Server 2022+:**

Starting from SQL Server 2022+, you may try `LEAD()` with the undocumented `IGNORE NULLS` option:

```
SELECT 
   r#, 
   COALESCE([value], LEAD([value]) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY r#)) AS [value]
FROM @value
ORDER BY r#
```

Comment: That CASE statement would look neater as `COALESCE(v1.[value], v2.[value]) AS [value]`

Comment: This looks like [The Last non NULL Puzzle](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle) where Itzik Ben-Gan presented very efficient solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can try below sql code using co-related subquery

```
SELECT v1.r#,CASE WHEN value IS NOT NULL THEN v1.Value     
             ELSE ( SELECT TOP 1 value
                    FROM @value  v2
                    WHERE v2.r# > v1.r# AND v2.[value] IS NOT NULL
                  ) END  Value 
FROM @value v1
```

OR (without Case statement)

```
SELECT v1.r#,ISNULL(v1.VALUE,( SELECT TOP 1 value
                            FROM @value  v2
                            WHERE v2.r# > v1.r# 
                            AND v2.[value] IS NOT NULL
                           ) 
                      ) AS [MonthNames]
FROM @value v1
```

Result

```
r#  Value
----------
1   January
2   January
3   February
4   March
5   March
6   December
7   December
8   December
9   November
10  November
11  November
12  November
13  NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

below query works in SQL Server:

```
;WITH CTE_Value
AS (
    SELECT R#, Value
    FROM @value AS T
    WHERE Value IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.r#, c.Value
    FROM @value AS t
    INNER JOIN CTE_Value AS c ON t.r# + 1 = c.r#
    WHERE t.Value IS NULL
    )
SELECT *
FROM CTE_Value

UNION ALL

SELECT v.*
FROM @value AS v
LEFT JOIN CTE_value AS c ON v.r# = c.r#
WHERE c.r# IS NULL
ORDER BY r#
```